# Como somar valor de uma célula condicionado ao valor de outra?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou tentando fazer esta soma em excel. Tenho os produtos com preços e os kits dos quais eles participam, mas não sei como fazer o cálculo do valor total para cada kit de forma automática.
Queria poder incluir e tirar os produtos dos kits e também alterar o preço de cada produto e os kits se atualizarem automaticamente. É possível?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de especificar cada kit que compõe o produto na coluna B, divida esta coluna em 3: Kit 1, Kit 2 e Kit 3, daí como por exemplo para o produto1, marque um "X" nas colunas correspondentes aos kits 1, 2 e 3 e faça uma fórmula condicional para ele somar apenas se tais células possuirem o "X".

Comment: Muito obrigado. Mais fácil do que eu imaginava. Estava tentando coisas bem mais difíceis que isso. Por isso não conseguia fazer. Problema resolvido. Abraço.